# Deal with huge JSON responses

Tags: java, android, rest, jackson

I think I need to rewrite some modules of my app because when the number of entities that are rendered increases, it fails and errors too. At this moment, I'm using `Jackson` and `HttpClient`.  As much as I trust in Jackson, something tells me that the problem is the second lib. Can `HttpClient` deal with large responses? (e.g. [this one](http://dpaste.com/0FWGRD9) that is about 400 lines)

Besides that, in my app, the way I parse the request goes something like this:

```
public Object handle(HttpResponse response, String rootName) {
    try {
        String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 
        // better "new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response)" ????
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if ( statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300 ) {
            return createObject(json, rootName);
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public Object createObject (String json, String rootName) {
    try {
        this.root = this.mapper.readTree(json);
        String className = Finder.findClassName(rootName);
        Class clazz = this.getObjectClass(className);
        return mapper.treeToValue(root.get(rootName), clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

How I can improve this piece of code to be more efficient with large responses?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the exact errors/exceptions you're running into? Have you looked at [Request/Response entity streaming](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html#Request_Response_entity_streaming)?

Comment: I can't remember it, however, what I need to use that streaming classes in Android? : o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create the `String json`, as [`ObjectMapper#readTree`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.io.InputStream)) can accept an `InputStream` as well. For example, this will be slightly more efficient:

```
public Object handle(HttpResponse response, String rootName) {
    try {
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if ( statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300 ) {
            return createObject(response.getEntity().getContent(), rootName);
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public Object createObject (InputStream json, String rootName) {
    try {
        this.root = this.mapper.readTree(json);
        String className = Finder.findClassName(rootName);
        Class clazz = this.getObjectClass(className);
        return mapper.treeToValue(root.get(rootName), clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it just before ask, but it gives me more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had 1000+ line json responses handled without issue, so that shouldnt be a problem. As for better ways of doing it, Google GSON is amazing, itll map your json to you java object with no special parsing code whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could read data to a good old StringBuffer. Something like

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
if (httpEntity != null) {
    InputStream is = AndroidHttpClient.getUngzippedContent(httpEntity);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8192);
    String s;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) sb.append(s);
}
```

Comment: i don't see how that would change anything.